# Removal of unique entries

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I am working with a hospital dataset in ACCESS 2010 that has records identified by patient number. I have 350,000 entries from around 200,000 unique patients. I want to REMOVE all those patients who appear only once or twice and RETAIN in a new table all the entries for patients who have at least 3 admissions. I need the resulting table to have multiple rows per patient (ie one row per admission) and not just one row presenting a count of appearances.

Answer (score 1):

From your description, I got the impression you already know how to create a `GROUP BY` query which shows you which patients have more than 2 admission records:

```sql
SELECT [patient number], Count(*)
FROM Admissions
GROUP BY [patient number]
HAVING Count(*) > 2;
```

But the issue is that you want to see the full records for those patients, not just the count of records for each patient.

So you can use the `GROUP BY` query as a subquery which you `INNER JOIN` back to the `Admissions` table.  The effect will be to filter the `Admissions` rows to only those for patients returned from the `GROUP BY`.

```sql
SELECT a.*
INTO NewTable
FROM
    Admissions AS a
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT [patient number]
        FROM Admissions
        GROUP BY [patient number]
        HAVING Count(*) > 2
    ) AS sub
    ON a.[patient number] = sub.[patient number];
```

I understood you want to store the data in a new table.  If I misunderstood your intention, and you only want to display the data, remove `INTO NewTable` from that query.

Answer (score 0):

**I don't know what is your data/table structure but TRY THIS STATEMENT form**

```
SELECT *
FROM [Patient]
WHERE PatNumber IN (SELECT PatNumber FROM [Patient] GROUP BY PatNumber HAVING  COUNT(PatNumber) > 2)
```